# retrieving check boxes and their nested check boxes through database

Tags: .net, sql

[image: Screen shot of table]

I am working on a project where I need client to select a list of check boxes although some check boxes contain nested check boxes that also needs to get selected (as desired by client).

Despite my numerous efforts, I could not deduce a way to save and show only the list of selected check boxes on the next page.

I am confused here. I have come to know about a lot of tools but they are all client based tools like `ajax` `accordion` etc.,. since I intend to use it over server side, all methods failed.

I intend to create a list of courses and branches to be selected by the institution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: could you show us some code? what have you tried ?

Comment: do you store the exhaustive list of courses and branches in your database or elsewhere? How to do you store the user selection of these courses/branches in DB?

Comment: @Vikdor Yes. i store it in my database And as user selects the check box , it gets stored in table in form of string.
hope that's what u wanted to know.

Comment: If possible, would you like to give a snapshot of the table that stores these details? Since you just have two levels viz. courses and branches, just want to see how you store them in your DB.

Comment: It is really hard to deduce what are you trying to do without come code or at least example...

Answer (score 0):

So ... checkboxes can have parent checkboxes.  The canonical structure is self-referential:

```
create table boxes ( box int primary key, parent int )
select a.*, b.box as 'sub-box'
from boxes as a join boxes as b on b.parent = a.box
```

That gives you one level.  To get the whole hierarchy, use a recursive view.